# How to export map from c++ to c# using Interop?

Tags: c#, c++, interop

Hi I have a code like this in c++

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool CallCustomObjectGetPropertyValue(AcDbObject* obj, long objId, std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>& mapToFill) {
    CustomObject* custom = dynamic_cast<CustomObject*>(obj);
    if (!custom) {
        acutPrintf(_T("\nERROR: custom object is nullptr"));
        return false;
    }
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> EmptyMapToFill = {};
    mapToFill = EmptyMapToFill;
```

I try assign empty map to mapToFill but i get error "read access violation.
_Head was 0x400.". I tried to assign char, string and it is ok for these types. What is problem with map ? What do i do wrong?

and C# invoking method

```
        [DllImport("SheetMetalSample.brx")]
        private static extern void CallCustomObjectGetPropertyValue(IntPtr obj, long objId, out IntPtr Int32mapPtr);
```

Tried to find answer how to do this but unsuccessful.

Comment: You can't. C# doesn't understand how to marshal `std::map` or `std::vector` and how to free the memory. Instead you need to have C# allocate a buffer, and C++ can write into it.

Comment: Build you c++ as a managed project.  Then you do not need to use DllImport : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/managed-types-cpp-cli?view=msvc-170

Comment: The C++ code is borken, it returns a reference to a local object whose lifetime ends at the end of the function.  Dangling pointer bugs tend to be more visible when you pinvoke, the marshaller does a good job of overwriting the stack content.  Use *new* to allocate the object on the heap, add pinvokable code to delete it again later.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

P/Invoke is a C-style API. There is a [marshaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/interop-marshalling) that can convert some types to corresponding C-types, but this only works for simple cases, like structs or arrays. It cannot handle C++ objects like std::Map or Vector.

Even worse, C++ has no Application binary interface (ABI). So different compilers may represent such objects differently. This means C++ may not even be able to use C++ libraries from another compiler. But it was a long time I coded C++, and I'm no expert in this topic.

Some possible alternatives:

1. Use P/Invoke and restrict yourself to a C API
2. Use C++/CLI to provide a .Net API for your C++ project
3. Implement a COM API
4. Run your native code in another process and use an inter process API.